# How to lookup into same collection in an array of id?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate, lookup

I have a user schema with

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
{
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  follows : [{
    type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
    ref : "User"
  }],
  followers : [{
    type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
    ref : "User"
  }],
});
```

I have a `userId`, and then I want to fetch all followers from that useriD. I am new to mongodb.

So a user have a field of followers[], it will containen the userid of all followers. So i want to fetch all fields of the followers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `$match` your user id condition
- `$lookup` to join, pass same collection name in `from`

```
User.aggregate([
  { $match: { _id: 1 } },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "user", // update to your actual collection name
      localField: "followers",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "followers"
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nNxk60_8uIa)

Answer (score 0):

As though followers refer to the User object id so it is good to use the find method in the userSchema.
suppose you are passing Id as a parameter then just find method.

```
const fields = await userSchema.find({ follower: req.params.id });
```

Comment: Actually i want to find the follwers's details follower's name, username his id. If he is my follower. I only have my id. And i want to get all the details of each followers

Comment: well. have you get your followers? if yes then just map that followers objects and access each item by map. it is just logical thinking of javascript.